# Get image width from input type file using javascript on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, file, input, width

This  http://jsfiddle.net/Mqvgx/ works on windows browsers but not on android phone.
Any ideas?

```
function getImgSize(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#testImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

$('#testImg').on('load',function(){
            alert($(this).width()+'*'+$(this).height());
        })

$("input").change(function(){
getImgSize(this);
});
```

Comment: It should work, FileReader has support in Android: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader Can you see the log of your app (maybe with logcat)?

Comment: I want to use the code with opera or other browsers on android. Will be an website not an app.